# What does the "are supposed, by some, to dream" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, american-english

No live organism can continue for long to exist sanely under conditions of absolute reality; even larks and katydids are supposed, by some, to dream.

Comment: This use of *[noun] is **supposed** to [verb]* (where ***supposed = thought / believed***, not ***ought / should / are intended to***) is dated / literary in ***all*** contexts. It's only "just about" licensed in the cited context because of interposed ***by some*** - without that, native speakers would naturally assign the ***ought / should*** sense to the words (and *then* conclude that the intended meaning was badly expressed, since ***ought*** doesn't actually make sense there).

Answer (score 2):

It means that some people suppose Larks and Katydids to be able to dream.

Another way of saying that would be "Some people believe that even larks and katydids can dream."

Comment: Some people *suppose larks and katydids are able to dream.*